# Adding a cell in Vue.js just doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, vue-good-table

I did a complete search about adding new fields in Vue.js 3 + Vite + VueGoodTable but it just doesn't work! It appears empty.

I used the codes from guide:  https://xaksis.github.io/vue-good-table/guide/advanced/#adding-custom-columns and from this https://jsfiddle.net/marekfilip/jm4ywzor/

Using the snippet from jsfiddles it only shows this:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8xv4.png

For the jsfiddle I only changed new Vue with:

```
<script>
    import { VueGoodTable } from 'vue-good-table-next';

    export default({
        components: {
            VueGoodTable
        },
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After extensive search came back to vue-good-table-next guide and changed 
`<template slot="table-row" slot-scope="props">`
to 
`<template #table-row="props">`

It worked! 
 I suppose is related tu Vue 3 and the new version of vue-good-table-next.

Sorry for the trouble.